# Spring: Which internal class inserts the @RequestBody parameter in controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public void triggerInvitations(@RequestBody String postBody)
```

Which Spring class does the actual task of reading the input stream and setting the request body in the parameter "`postBody`"?

Actually, I'm just getting the response status as `400 Bad Request` and unable to see the actual cause. As such, I wanted to debug the Spring code and know exactly the reason why its a bad request. (If I don't have a `@RequestBody` parameter in the controller signature, control is able to reach the method)

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8

Comment: How are you sending your request?

Answer (score 0):

There are different HTTP Message converters used by Spring. This [article](https://baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) will give you an overview of this and also list different message converters.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your springframework debugging in your application.properties:

> logging.level.org.springframework = DEBUG

It should start to show you why it's not matching the request to your RequestMapping.